# Access denied when accessing properties from inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

In my HTML page I have an `iframe` loading an external site. I want to access the properties inside the frame. I am getting an access denied error. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

[You can't access data from external sites](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) when you are working client side. This would be a security risk.

To work around, have your server grab the data from the remote site instead.